# solved! why is my character not going up slopes, (unity 3d using A*)

Tags: unity-game-engine, a-star

solved. max climb in A* and step offset in character controller had to be set to much higher.

my character is refusing to go up slopes, he just gets there and then stops. is has that error message i don't understand, and both the character controller, and the A*, have a slope limit of 90

as it turns out, the character also refuses to go down slopes. i moved my target around the bean and it only moved left and right while neither moving up and down.

this is the code for the bean

```
 public Transform target;
public Vector3 targetPosition;

private Seeker seeker;
private CharacterController controller;

public Path path;

public float speed = 100;

public float nextWaypointDistance = 3;

private int currentWaypoint = 0;


public void Start()
{
    targetPosition = target.transform.position;
    seeker = GetComponent<Seeker>();
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

    seeker.StartPath(transform.position, targetPosition, OnPathComplete);
}

public void OnPathComplete(Path p)
{
    //Debug.Log ("Yey, we got a path back. Did it have an error? "+p.error);
    if (!p.error)
    {
        path = p;
        //Reset the waypoint counter
        currentWaypoint = 0;
    }
}

public void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (path == null)
    {
        //We have no path to move after yet
        return;
    }

    if (currentWaypoint >= path.vectorPath.Count)
    {
        if (targetPosition != target.transform.position)
        {
            targetPosition = target.transform.position;
            seeker.StartPath(transform.position, targetPosition, OnPathComplete);
        }
    }

    //Direction to the next waypoint
    Vector3 dir = (path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint] - transform.position).normalized;
    dir *= speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    controller.Move(dir);
    

    //Check if we are close enough to the next waypoint
    //If we are, proceed to follow the next waypoint
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint]) < nextWaypointDistance)
    {
        currentWaypoint++;
        return;
    }
    if(targetPosition != target.transform.position)
    {
        targetPosition = target.transform.position;
        seeker.StartPath(transform.position, targetPosition, OnPathComplete);
    }
```

the error is ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index, but now it is fixed.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Character Controller has a property for this called `stepOffset`.  From the docs: `The character will step up a stair only if it is closer to the ground than the indicated value. This should not be greater than the Character Controller’s height or it will generate an error.`  There is also the `slopeLimit` which `Limits the collider to only climb slopes that are less steep (in degrees) than the indicated value.`